# Law of demeter does not apply in this case?

Tags: java

Suppose I have a function which takes in a List of objects, something like:

```
class A{
  C c;
  C getC();
}

Class C{
  boolean propBool;
  boolean getPropBool();
}

public void someThing(List<A> lst){ 
  for(A a : lst){
    if(a.getC().getPropBool()){
      //do some stuff
    }
  }
}
```

On face value, this looks like a violation of the Law of demeter since I am accessing A, then accesing the inner object `C`, then inside `C` I am accessing `propBool`.

The problem is, i am not too sure how to rewrite this to not violate the law of demeter.

Writing a helper which takes in C seems extremely useless.

```
public boolean getPropBoolFRomC(C c){
  return c.getPropBool();
}
```

Whats the approach here?

Comment: I'ts not so much a "law" as a "guideline" ;)  Don't go overboard - just use common sense.  If you follow the [KISS Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle), generally everything else will follow.  Including he "loose coupling, high cohesion" the so-called "Law of Demeter" is intended to promote..  PS: The answer to your question is inevitably a matter of opinion.

Comment: Given its a made up example its hard to say what is right or wrong here. IMO if your concerned about the function taking a `List<A>` but it should only care about a the object `C` then you should just take a `List<C>`. Or if your on Java > 8 then you could make it `Stream<C>` then do `someThing(a.stream().map(v -> v.getC()));`

Answer (score 1):

The [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) (LoD) is not really a law.  It is actually just a design principle.  It is generally helpful, but by no means universally applicable. You can ignore it if you think it is not applicable (or helpful) to your use-case.  Nobody will take you to court for violating the LoD.

In your use-case, you would need to decide if `C` is an implementation detail of `A` or not, and whether it is a good thing to hide it.  The Law of Demeter doesn't answer that question for you.  You need to decide for yourself, according to the specific needs of your use-case.

However, if you decide that `C` *is* an implementation detail of `A` and that it *should* be hidden then the Law of Demeter says that you should implement something like the helper function.  In this context it is not "extremely useless".  It has a specific purpose ... which is to hide the implementation detail.  I would write it like this:

```
public class A {
  private C c;
  private C getC() {...}
  public getTheProperty() {
    return this.getC().getPropBool();
  }
}

class C {
  private boolean propBool;
  boolean getPropBool();
}
```

(This is one of those cases where you *cannot* have it both ways.  Either the LoD applies and the helper is not useless, or it doesn't apply.)

Note that we cannot advise you on whether LoD should be applied here.  Your example is too abstract.  A valid judgement can only be made in the context of a realistic application design.

Comment: Basically, all I actually need is `C` and `C.getPropBool()`, but `C` is a field in `A` and I am given a `List<A>`, one person did say you could change the params to take in a `Stream<C>` (so give it a `lst.stream().map(A::getC)` instead, which makes more sense, but then the helper would only have two lines, which would be `stream.anyMatch(C::getPropBool)`, its hard to decide whats correct here.

Comment: So, if C is not a hidden implementation detail of A, then this is not a case where the LoD applies.  In this example, your original version is correct (IMO).  The stream solution is equivalent to your original version from the LoD perspective.

Comment: Nice answer, can you briefly explain what exactly you mean by `implementation detail`?

Comment: It is like ... do you want clients of the API to know about and potentially depend on this aspect ... or not.

Comment: Sorry, English is not my first language, which API are we taking about? API of `A` or API of `C`? Basically, the `someThing` function really only needs a `List<C>`, because if you see, it doesnt care at all about any other field of `A`, however I have a `List<A>` not a `List<C>` available. I'm still unsure what implementation details mean in this context. The `someThing` function only cares about `C`, not about `A`

Comment: I am talking in general terms.  It is up to you to decide what classes comprise your API, and how much of the implementation detail you want (need) to hide.

Comment: However, obviously, the API must be designed to be usable.  So if you only have a `List<A>` then *either* your `someThing` needs to know about `A.getC` *or* you need to implement some separate functionality to map a `List<A>` to a `List<C>` so that you can provide the method with what it ... needs.  (And if you take the 2nd approach, you have to ask yourself if it is really worth the effort and the runtime overheads.)

Comment: In an ideal world, `someThing` would get a `List<C>`. I could pass it in a `Stream<C>` and implement in a functional way. That is kind of what I am actually doing but i am creating the `Stream<C>` in the `someThing` function. What do you think of this?

Comment: That's OK.  Actually, any of the alternatives is OK.  It is just that if you create the `Stream<C>` within `someThing`, then that method needs to be aware of the relationship between `A` and `C` ... which is the root of your original LoD concern.

Comment: Yeah thats true, which is why I was a bit hesistant, but I think since this is only one level nesting it should be fine, not worth it complicating the API further to take in a `Stream<C>` and doing other computation outside `someThing`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are doing in that `if` you rewrite code like that

```
for (A a : lst) {
    a.getC().doStuff();
}
```

And inside `C.doStuff()` check that boolean and implement logic.

Comment: I still think this is a violation of demeter law.